# Dataset datatable formatting rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i have a dataset which contains a table retrieved from sql. It has 'product' column and 'price' column. I got the dataset and binded to grid. Now i want to make the grid's price column to be formatted to 2 decimal places(validation). Any idea please. 
I should not change the select query since its an SP which gives me the dataset.

Comment: Ok thanks.I am yet to start with it. Just one more question, i have to validate that too. So how can it be done. i mean to say its an editable grid so once done with editing while saving it must be validated for 2 decimal places also with rounding of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

if you neither want to use Bound-Field nor change select query than as much i know you have two options left to accomplish this. First is, do value change in your dataset before binding to grid using any loop  and the second option is alter values in grid on RowDataBound Event...

**By altering value in Dataset:**

```
 foreach(dataRow[] dr in dataset.tables[your table index])
 {
  // max. two decimal places
   string val =   String.Format("{0:0.##}",Convert.ToDecimal(dr[column index])); 
   dr[column index] = val;
 }
```

**By altering value in Grid:**

```
  protected void mygrid_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            mygrid.cell[cell index].Text =   String.Format("{0:0.##}",Convert.ToDecimal(dataset.tables[table index][column index][Row Index]));               

        }
    }
```

Now if you want apply validation for data insert and update you can apply RegularExpressionValidator at your textBox ...

```
   <EditItemTemplate>
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"     ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator"
        ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationExpression="^\d{1,2}([.]\d{1})$"> ValidationGroup="MyVal"</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Now you have to apply

> ValidationGroup="MyVal"

also on click control on which you'll perform its editing and update..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Price" DataFormatString="{0:C2}" HeaderText="Price" />
```

You need to add the "DataFormatString" property to the bound field as shown above. This formats currency values to two decimal places. [Check this article](http://programming.top54u.com/Samples/ASP-Net-cs/GridView-Control/GridView-DataFormatString/Default.aspx).

DataField refers to the name of the column in the datatable, whereas the HeaderText refers to the text which would be shown as the header of the column in grid.

Comment: Thanks for your help but i should not use boundfield in design page as per standards. Any way will recommend that. Please let me know if any other way to achevie

Comment: [Check this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb426882.aspx). Let me know if you are able to achieve what you desire.

Comment: @sam. To make sure that the user enters the input in some particular format, you need to convert the boundfield to templatefield. Check the article above.